# Separating the data from a string filled with multiple data types

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

I want to turn this string into a list of the dictionaries within it:

`”[{‘id’: ‘x’, ‘name’: ‘y’}, {‘id’: ‘p’, ‘name’: ‘q’}]”`

I have multiple columns in a pandas dataframe composed of similar strings to this. Some are only `”[]”` or `”[{‘id’: ‘x’, ‘name’: ‘y’}]”`, and others have many stringified dictionaries within them.

I have tried

```py
import json
z = ”[{‘id’: ‘x’, ‘name’: ‘y’}, {‘id’: ‘p’, ‘name’: ‘q’}]”
list(json.loads(z[1:-1]))
```

And this works fine for when there is only one stringified dictionary (`”[{‘id’: ‘x’, ‘name’: ‘y’}]”`) but because the dictionaries have shared keys, they cannot simply be  jsonified.

Once this is done, I’ll retrieve the value from `name` of each and create a list of those.

**ANSWERED**
Thanks [@Tenacious B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12442479/tenacious-b)

To turn the string into the list of the dicts:

```py
import json
z = ”[{‘id’: ‘x’, ‘name’: ‘y’}, {‘id’: ‘p’, ‘name’: ‘q’}]”
data = json.loads(z.replace("'", ""))]) # this will be a list of dicts
```

Output:

```py
[{'id': 'x', 'name': 'y'}, {'id': 'p', 'name': 'q'}]
```

---

**And** to apply to a pandas dataframe having a column with entries as the above, retrieving only the value from the desired key:

```py
import json
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in json.loads(x.replace("'", ""))])
```

Comment: your json is invalid in the  example, starts with a list at the root node but ends with a curly bracket

Comment: @TenaciousB that looks like a typo. It ends with a `]` in the first example.

Comment: it was a typo, thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same keys in different dicts/json objects, also to `loads()` you need to replace the `'` with `"`:

```py
import json
z = "[{'id': 'x', 'name': 'y'}, {'id': 'p', 'name': 'q'}]"
data = json.loads(z.replace("'", '"')) # this will be a list of dicts
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 'x', 'name': 'y'}, {'id': 'p', 'name': 'q'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue with the shared keys was related to combining all of the dicts into a single dict without an index identifying the different dicts; I DO want exactly that, a list with dicts that have the same keys. Excellent! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After I searched up how to convert a string list to list object I came across this: [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894293/6635590)

using `ast.literal_eval` can solve you problem.

Comment: Also an excellent solution! I chose @tenacious-b solution based on its extension of my proposed method. I will keep this method in mind in the future, it's very slick